# Probability question to find out faulty screws within a certain box

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A factory produces 350 metal screws a day with 40 of those being found to be faulty.

In a box of screws there are 52 screws. How many of these screws are expected to be faulty?

I've been learning probability as part of my uni course, however, I'm struggling with how to calculate?

In terms of the question above, do I need to work out 350/40 then apply the result of that to the box of screws? i.e. 52/8.75 with the result shown as a fraction?

Comment: Hint: how many screws do you expect to be faulty in a box of 350? In a box of 700? In a box of 35? In a box of 70? Can you write an equation expressing the relationship?

Comment: Yes, $52/8.75$ is correct.  This can be formalized by referencing the fact that expectation is linear.  As an aside, I would prefer to see the answer written as $52\cdot\frac{40}{350}$ as it is easier to follow at a glance where the numbers came from rather than using $8.75$

Comment: its how many are faulty in the box of 52 bearing in mind that of the 350 produced daily 40 of them are deemed faulty.

Comment: So would the answer in this case be 5.94? or 297/50